# In ZFC, does every object live in the superset given by some ordinal?

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

In the paper "Internal Set Theory: A New Approach to Nonstandard Analysis", Edward Nelson gives the following definition and claim during his proof of the conservativity of ZFC + IST over ZFC:

"We let $R(0) = \emptyset$ and define by transfinite induction for all ordinals we let
\begin{align*}
R(\alpha) = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} P(R(\beta)).
\end{align*}
Every set $x$ is in $R(\alpha)$ for some ordinal $\alpha$."

The broader context for this claim is that Nelson is building a sufficiently large universe such that given a formula $A$, its truth is equivalent to its truth when the free variables are bounded within that smaller universe.

While it is my understanding that all familiar mathematical objects can be built (at least in principle) out of the empty set, it is unclear to me how we rule out the existence of objects whose existence is not guaranteed by any of the axioms. Is this statement true?

For context, my background in ZFC is Paul Halmos' "Naive Set Theory", and my background in logic is Herbert Enderton's "An Introduction to Mathematical Logic".

Comment: This won't be true without the axiom of foundation (a set $x$ such that $x =\{x\}$ certainly won't be picked up by this construction which can only produce well-founded sets). Given the axiom of foundation, then it should follow from Hartog's lemma or something similar.

Comment: The levels themselves are all sets, as a result of being constructed by transfinite recursion, because the levels are transitive, any set in a level is a subset of the level- and so exists by the comprehension axiom

Comment: @RobArthan Assuming the axiom of foundation, Hartog's would still only guarantee an injection into some $R(\alpha)$. Is there some kind of theorem that formulas in ZFC are equivalent to ones where sets are replaced by their embeddings in some other set?

Comment: Actually, you don't need Hartog's lemma. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity, particularly the section titled "Every set has an ordinal rank". I wouldn't describe the phenomenon the way you do: my take is that given the axiom of foundation, all sets are known to be constructed from thin air (or more precisely from the empty set and transfinite iteration of power set and union).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\text{WF} = \cup_{\alpha\in\text{Ord}} R(\alpha)$.  Let $S$ be any set.  By replacing $S$ by
$$\operatorname{TrCl}(S) = \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \left(\cup^n S\right)$$

we may assume $S$ is a transitive set.  (A transitive set is a set such that $\cup S\subseteq S\subseteq P(S)$).
Note that if $S\subseteq R(\gamma)$ then $S\in R(\gamma+1)$, so we need to prove there is some $\gamma$ for which $S\subseteq R(\gamma)$.

If for all $y\in S, y\in\text{WF}$, let $F(y)$ by the least ordinal $\tau$ for which $y\subseteq R(\tau)$.  By an instance of the axiom of replacement, $\{F(y)+1:y\in S\}$ is a set, so there's an ordinal $\gamma=\sup\{F(y)+1:y\in S\}$.  Since for each $y\in S$, $y\subseteq R(F(y))$ then $y\in R(F(y)+1)\subseteq R(\gamma)$.  This proves $S\subseteq R(\gamma)$ which is what we wanted to show.

So finally, assume by contradiction that $S\setminus WF \ne \emptyset$.  Since $S\setminus WF \subseteq S$, it is a set (by an instance of the axiom of comprehension.)  So by the axiom of regularity, $S\setminus WF$ has an $\in$-minimal member.  Let's call it $z$.  If $p\in z$ then $p\in S$ because $z\in S$ and $S$ is transitive.  Because of the $\in$-minimality of $z$ it follows that $p\not\in S\setminus WF$, so $p\in\text{WF}$.  So all members of $z$ are in $\text{WF}$.  By the same argument used in the previous paragraph, it follows that $z\in\text{WF}$ - in contradicition to the assumption that $z\in S\setminus\text{WF}$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Follow-up question: is ZFC + regularity known to be consistent (relative to ZFC or ZF)?